# Kotlin default arguments in interface bug?

Tags: kotlin

kotlin file

```
interface Test {

    fun test(message: String, delay: Int =100)
}

class A: Test
{
    override fun test(message: String, delay: Int) {
    }

}
```

I find i can't use `@JvmOverloads` in interface nor class.

if i add a `@JvmOverloads` in interface,the error is `@JvmOverloads annotation cannot be used on interface method`,if i add `@JvmOverloads` in class,the error is `platform declaration clash....`

However, I seem able to use defaults paramters in kotlin files,like this.

```
var a=A()
a.test("1234")
```

But when I use it in a java file, it seems that the method is not overloaded。

```
A a=new A();
a.test("123");//Compile error
```

The following version without interface can work

```
class A
{
    @JvmOverloads
     fun test(message: String, delay: Int=100) {
    }

}
```

Then I can use it normally in java file

```
 A a=new A();
 a.test("123");
```

But how to maintain the same functionality after add the interface?

Answer (score 13):

This is not a bug. `@JvmOverloads` annotation simply does not work with abstract methods.

From Kotlin docs:

> Normally, if you write a Kotlin function with default parameter values, it will be visible in Java only as a full signature, with all parameters present. If you wish to expose multiple overloads to Java callers, you can use the @JvmOverloads annotation.
>
> The annotation also works for constructors, static methods etc. **It can't be used on abstract methods, including methods defined in interfaces**.

source: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#overloads-generation

Why?
Because as You can learn from the doc I mentioned, `@JvmOverloads` instructs compiler to generate bunch of Java overloaded methods, omitting each of the parameters one by one, starting from the last one.
<s>As far as I understand, each overloaded method calls internally method with one more parameter, and this additional parameter has default value.</s> Edit: see comment by @hotkey [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070968/kotlin-default-arguments-in-interface-bug/47073705#comment81096836_47073705)

This won't work with abstract methods, because they don't have any body.
Also new Java interface would have more methods, and its implementations would have to implement all of them. Kotlin interface had only one method.

Comment: A minor correction: *each overloaded method calls internally method with one more parameter* -- it is not true, instead, for each function `foo` with default parameters an additional method `foo$default` is generated that also receives a bit mask telling which parameters should be replaced with the default ones. This method is also called by all the overloads generated with `@JvmOverloads`.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey for clarification. Edited answer with link to Your comment.

Comment: Of course you can overload interface methods. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You can define an interface with overloaded methods, but implementation of this interface cannot overload those methods. But, after thinking a while, there is no interface implementation here. I will edit my answer.

Comment: _This won't work with abstract methods, because they don't have any body. Also new Java interface would have more methods, and its implementations would have to implement all of them_ -- since when interface methods cannot have a body? Default methods in interfaces have been a thing since java 8 and classes have to implement only methods without default body.

Answer (score 0):

To get to the same result you can make a LegacySupport class in Kotlin that will actually call the function with the default parameter and then you can expose only the return of the function to the java class from this class.